# Web Service needs to execute Access Application

Tags: .net, user-interface, service

I have a web service running on the server and the web service needs to shell out and run a gui application.  This application runs on it's own, but it has some windows that it pops up to display.  Currently as soon as the application gets to any point where is pops up a window, the application dies.

Answer (score 1):

There **has** to be a better way.  If the app is written in Access, *anything* you need it to do could be done better in your web service's code, accessing only the data from Access.  I guarantee you'll have major heartaches if you try to do what you're suggesting.

Comment: This is an external application that is developed by another vendor.  They have a command line utility to run their application from the command line, but it pops up all their windows as the program runs automated.  I have to be able to run this from a command line.